# INVALID_ENUM with webGL drawElements

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, inspector

I´m coding my own **webGL engine/framework**, but something weird is happening:
I´m drawing a simple plane (2 triangles, just for testing) geometry with

`gl.drawElements( drawMode , geometry.numItems , gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT , 0 ) ;`
where drawmode is a variable with `gl.TRIANGLES` stored,
and `geometry.numItems` is the length of indices array.
All other buffers and stuff is properly set. In fact the object renders OK...

but cheking the debuging trace with webGL inspector in chrome I always see the error
**" drawElements( TRIANGLES, 6 , UNSIGNED_SHORT , 0 ) " as INVALID_ENUM.**
With this geometry and with any other.

[screenshot from webGL inspector showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TdhR.jpg)
So I don't understand what is going so wrong here, and why if something is going so wrong the obejcts are rendering ok.
Any idea ?

Comment: Does it behave any differently if you put `gl.TRIANGLES` in directly, rather than the cached value? I really doubt that it would, but that's the only thing that comes to mind right away.

Comment: It might not be that instruction it itself that is the root of the problem - it could be, for example, that you've bound an incorrect buffer. Not sure, but worth a look. Can you post the entire code leading up to the draw?